# Unable to separate items when displayed to listview android studio

Tags: android, android-listview, android-arrayadapter

I am in the process of learning Android, so far I have started on creating a Contact List. The list is stored using SQLlight, but when I try to display the information in a ListView each contact shows in the same section.

The result I get is..

contact 1

contact 2

contact 3

.......................

Instead of..

contact 1

.........................

contact 2

.........................

contact 3

.........................

```
public class MainActivityFragment extends Fragment {
DatabaseHelper mydb;
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
private static ListView listView;


public MainActivityFragment() {
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    mydb = new DatabaseHelper(getActivity());

    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(
            //gets information about MainActivity/ this fragment's parent activity
            getActivity(),
            //Id for contact item layout
            R.layout.contact_list_item,
            //gets the arraylist of contacts
            getContacts()
            );

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);

    //Get reference  to the list view and then set the adapter to it.
    listView = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.listView_contacts);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);

    return rootView;
}
/*
Method to get contacts from the Database
 */
public List<String> getContacts(){

    Cursor result = mydb.getData();
    List<String> nameList = new ArrayList<String>();

    if(result.getCount() == 0){
        nameList.add("No Contacts available");
        return nameList;
    }

    StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
    while(result.moveToNext()){
        //buffer.append("ID :" + result.getString(0)+"\n");
        buffer.append("Name :" + result.getString(1)+"\n");
        buffer.append("Phone :" + result.getString(2)+"\n");
        buffer.append("Email :" + result.getString(3)+"\n");
        buffer.append("B-Day :" + result.getString(4) + "\n");

    }
    nameList.add(buffer.toString());
    return nameList;
}
```

}

activity_main.xml

```
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:id="@+id/fragment"
android:name="com.example.jak.contacts.MainActivityFragment"
tools:layout="@layout/fragment_main" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

fragment_main.xml

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivityFragment"
android:orientation="vertical">

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Add Contact"
    android:id="@+id/button_Add_Contact"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|bottom" />

<ListView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="410dp"
    android:id="@+id/listView_contacts"
    android:layout_gravity="right"
    />
```

contact_list_item.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:id="@+id/contact_list_item_textView">
```

Comment: what do you mean same section ? is it visually ? same section ? or they literally are added in the same list item ?

Comment: How can you tell they are all in same position? You are using just TextView and what you see is probably three text views as it should. What happens if you click on each contact? Do you see all selected or one at a time?

Comment: They are all selected when I try to tap on only 1. Instead of a divider line after each individual contact there is only 1 divider line under them all.

Comment: Thanks for the responses, I figured out the issue. I was not retrieving the information correctly from the database.